# Add inner element to an XmlArray (Xml.Serialization)

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I'm having troubles when serializing a .net type and complying to an XML schema that add an additional container element (List in this case) to a sequence of elements:

```
<Items>                        
  <List>                 
   <Item>
     <Field1/>
     <Field2/>
   </Item>
   <Item>
     <Field1/>
     <Field2/>
   </Item>
  </List>           
</Items>
```

it seems that the XmlArray attribute gives only the possibility to map a single element (items) :

```
[XmlArray("items", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(OrderItemsItem), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public OrderItemsItem[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look at this, and the only way I can see to shape the data like that is to model it with that extra level in your model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Items = { new OrderItemsItem(), new OrderItemsItem() } };
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, foo);

    }

}
public class OrderItemsItem { }
public class Foo
{
    private FooItems items = new FooItems();

    // this one is for serialization, but tried to be invisible otherwise
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement("Items")]
    public FooItems WrappedItems { get { return items; } set { items = value; } }

    // this one is for general use
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<OrderItemsItem> Items { get { return items.Items; } }

    public class FooItems
    {
        private readonly List<OrderItemsItem> items = new List<OrderItemsItem>();
        [XmlArray("List"), XmlArrayItem("Item")]
        public List<OrderItemsItem> Items { get { return items; } }
    }
}
```